# Построение КА на основании БНФ

Tags: конечные-автоматы, лексический-анализатор

Добрый день, коллеги! При разработке своего веб-сервера столкнулся со следующей проблемой: я хочу выполнять лексический анализ `http`-запроса с помощью конечных автоматов, а для этого мне нужно знать, как построить НКА на основании существующих в [описании протокола HTTP RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) БНФ. Например, request-line описывается продукцией, в которую входит продукция метода, space`а, URI и версии HTTP и задается следующим образом:

```
Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

А вот продукция для описания `Method``а:

```
Method         = "OPTIONS"                
                      | "GET"             
                      | "HEAD"            
                      | "POST"            
                      | "PUT"             
                      | "DELETE"          
                      | "TRACE"           
                      | "CONNECT"         
                      | extension-method
```

Ну и соответственно далее можно было бы привести описание остальных продукций, но, я думаю, смысл понятен. То есть мы имеем продукцию, которая состоит из других продукций, которые состоят из других продукций и т.п.

В общем, как построить на основании этого конечный автомат, я примерно представляю ("лобовое" решение). Но все же хотелось бы узнать про существующие классические решения и алгоритмы для построение конечного автомата (который будет выполнять функцию лексера) на основании БНФ или какой-либо КС-грамматики.

P.S. Прошу не предлогать решения из "коробки", меня интересует, как это сделать самому.

Comment: вы хотите лексический анализатор или грамматический анализатор?

Comment: Мне нужен лексический анализатор

Comment: На всякий случай добавлю, что под "влобным" решением я имел ввиду иерархический конечный автомат.